# Setting gdb breakpoints into GTK+2 shared libraries?

Tags: linux, gdb, gtk2

I'm working on Centos6.3 -- Gtk-2.18 for a C(++) app. I'm having trouble with Metacity hanging when I set breakpoints in GTK libraries. It looks like the breakpoint is affecting the system-wide copy of the library, ie Metacity's, not just my app's and I have to force-restart my VM. Is there a way to force copy-on-write semantics for those shared libraries?

BTW, I don't have the GTK2.18 source -- the link is dead on http://www.gtk.org/download/linux.php --- is there working mirror somewhere? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The breakpoint is not system-wide.  Instead, what is most likely happening is that your program is hitting the breakpoint while it has a server grab.  This prevents your other windows from receiving events.

There are different ways to work around this.  Some GUI toolkits (I don't remember about Gtk) have a way to prevent grabs, to facilitate debugging.  Or, you can debug remotely from another machine.  Or, similarly, in a VM or using a virtual X server for the program you are debugging.